# XML-Indention messed up after `document.setXmlStandalone(true)`

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm creating an XML document with DOM:

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
//document.setXmlStandalone(true);

Element root = document.createElement("root");
document.appendChild(root);
root.appendChild(document.createElement("childElement"));
document.insertBefore(document.createComment("some comment"), root);
```

I want to output the generated XML prettily and used this to achieve it:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

Until this point it works pretty fine but the output messes up the XML-Comment i added before the root element of the document. Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--some comment--><root>
  <childElement/>
</root>
```

And if I uncomment the line `//document.setXmlStandalone(true)` it messes up the formatting even more:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--some comment--><root>
  <childElement/>
</root>
```

---

As you can easily see, the newlines after the comment (and in the second example after the prolog) are missing!

In C++ the XML library xerces-c++ can handle those problems by adding a text-node before the root node (which only consists of a newline character), but that doesn't work with Java-DOM!

Is there any way (*besides adding the comment and the prolog myself*) to make DOM format my Xml properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I put Saxon 9.7 HE on the class path (so that Saxon is then used as the Transformer) the code

```
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    document.setXmlStandalone(true);

    Element root = document.createElement("root");
    document.appendChild(root);
    root.appendChild(document.createElement("childElement"));
    document.insertBefore(document.createComment("some comment"), root);

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

produces the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--some comment-->
<root>
   <childElement/>
</root>
```

Perhaps that is an option for you, it gives you XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0/3.0 if needed in your project in addition to the improvement of the indentation.